# Deploying Data-Tier Application (DAC) which contains multiple Composite Databases Fails

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, dac, dacpac

I have a SSDT Project (call it ConsumerSSDTProject) which references one Same Server/Different Database project (contains stored procedures to "extend" master; MstExtSSDTProject), and two references to a Same Server/Same Database project (AddObjsSSDTProjectA and B). The Include composite objects option is checked for all projects.

When I publish from MSVS 2010 with SSDT (version 10.2.21208.0; SQL Server Data Tools - December 2012 and Data-Tier Application Framework - May 2013) the composite/referenced database objects are also published correctly (objects are added and/or updated properly in the target database or master).

When I run the ConsumerSSDTProject's DACPAC file from "Deploy Data-Teir Application" within SSMS 2012 none of the composite/referenced objects are deployed which results in the objects within the ConsumerSSDTProject which depend on these referenced objects to fail.

I beleive the deployment of the DACPAC work before I upgraded the Data-Tier Application Framework to May 2013 but my memory could be wrong since it has been over a month since I deployed using the SSMS wizard.

So my questions are:

1) Does the SSMS Deploy Data-Tier Application wizard behave like the MSVS publisher (includes the deployment of the composite/referenced projects)?

2) If so, what options, components, etc. am I mssing or not enabled to get these features working with a DACPAC deployment?

3) if DACPAC does not support this, what other options do I have other than using a script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on [Deploying Data-Tier Application (DAC) which contains multiple Composite/Referenced Databases in SSMS 2012 via "Deploy Data-Tier Application" wizard fails...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/186a1f32-8e88-41a0-b862-07199ff04dde/#5539585d-29d2-4a02-9d8a-a25d3f27e381)

Comment: There is only a link to some article which does not answer the question.